# ¿como invocar una función de un componente hijo desde un componente padre?

Tags: angular

Buen día.

Tengo una función en un componente hijo la cual se encarga de setear un valor en una sección.
Esta acción debería ser ejecutada desde un botón que tengo en el componente padre.

Como podría invocar esta función que tengo en un componente hijo desde el componente padre?

Comment: Seria bueno que pongas un ejemplo del código para entender mejor, pero de antemano si usas Angular 2 + puedes usar EventEmitter https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer desde el html, en el padre tendras algo asi:

```
<componente-hijo>
       ...
<componente-hijo/>
```

Dale un nombre al hijo e invoca a tu función.

```
<componente-hijo #hijo>
       ...
<componente-hijo/>

<div>
    <button (click)="hijo.miFuncion()">Boton</button>
<div/>
```

Espero sea util